# How can I install Pytorch version 1.1 on Windows x64?

Tags: python, windows, pytorch

I need to install an older version of Pytorch, version 1.1, on my Windows 10 x64 machine.

The [instructions here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/) tell me to download the wheel and install it. However, `pip` refuses to install this wheel, claiming it is not supported on my platform. I suppose that is because, judging by the the name of the wheel (`torch-1.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`) it is meant for AMD, and I'm on an Intel i7. I found no better matching wheel on the Pytorch site.

What is the easiest way to install Pytorch 1.1 on my machine?

Comment: Hi, I believe the error to actually be with the python version!

Comment: cp37 means that you need CPython version 3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`conda`](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/)

```
conda install pytorch=1.1.0
```

I've checked the exisiting versions with `conda search -f pytorch` and `1.1.0` ([and many others too](https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/)) is available.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Comment: @AvivCohn Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The current error is most likely because you are running Python 32 Bit, or a different CPython version. The following answer is solving the CPython version error. I couldn't find any 32bit python versions of pytorch.

---

Before using this solution, make sure you are using 64-bit **Python**, not OS! You can check this using the following code in command prompt:

```
>python
>import platform
>platform.architecture()
```

If it says '64bit', this solution should work. If not, download a 64-bit version of python. Unfortunately, I don't know any other alternative.

---

There are multiple different Pytorch versions for 1.1.0 if you want to use a GPU or want to be CPU only.

```
For Cuda 10.0: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch_stable.html
For Cuda 9.0: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu90/torch_stable.html
For CPU only: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html
```

Then use `ctrl+f` to search for:

```
torch-1.1.0-cp{CPython version}-cp{CPython version}m-win_AMD64.whl
```

Replace `{Cpython version}` with your python version, for example 37 for 3.7.

Then download that file. Install using:

```
pip install <path to wheel file>
```

Comment: Sorry for the links being in the code formatting, it wouldn't let me share them as links, the editor said that I was "incorrectly formatting code"!